# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid default value for 'ver_date'

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a spec file which specifies the table structure and java programme creates the table on installation,
The spec file is as below,

```
customer {
    attributes = [
        { name : custId, type ="string:100" , key=true}
        { name : ver-date, type: timestamp , key=true}
        { name : updates, type = "string:8000" }
        { name : created-date, type : timestamp }
        { name : created-userId, type = "string:200" }
        { name : verifier-userId, type = "string:200" }
        { name : remark, type = "string:8000" }
    ]
}

The corresponding generated create statment fails with error as below as below,
Query executed : CREATE TABLE `customer` ( 
`verifier_userId` VARCHAR(200) binary ,
`custId` VARCHAR(100) binary ,
 `remark` VARCHAR(8000) binary ,
 `created_date` timestamp  NULL,
 `ver_date` timestamp ,
 `updates` VARCHAR(8000) binary ,
 `created_userId` VARCHAR(200) binary ,
  primary key (`custId`,`ver_date`))
**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid default value for 'ver_date'**
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2495)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1903)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2124)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2058)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5158)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2043)
at     com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:384)
```

The problem looks like the ver_date is not given a default value when it is a primary key, as it cannot have null also.

The challenge here is that we cannot change the spec file, as well as the java programme which is generating the 'create statement'.

The database version used is as below,
*mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.29, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper*

Is there any setting in the database server which will impact this and can be modified to ensure it works? Really appreciate the help.

Comment: I would suggest you avoid using `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL, since it's not greatly implemented an is error prone. You can use `DATETIME` instead, and is much more consistent.

Comment: Since `ver_date` is a key, how can you insert NULL for it's default value?

Comment: By the way, there's no version 14 for MySQL. Latest one is 8.x

Comment: It cannot have null and data is not even a problem now. As of now creating the table is our priority. Please help. @The Impaler we cannot change the spec as it is provided by the customer.

Comment: You should have custId alone as primary key.

Comment: But what if someone wants a query with timstamp comarison. Ofcourse equals will not be possible but greater than\less than?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have kept the sql_mode as empty and then it worked.